# how are global variables stored differently in memory than local variables

Tags: operating-system, stack, memory-address

I'm reading a book on operating systems and it says "we must set things up so that the portion of the added space allocated to global variables tensions allocated for the life time of the program, but that portion allocated for a local variable remains allocated only while the thread is in the variables scope"

What I don't understand is when a program is loaded into memory isn't the addresses reserved for it static? It's not like when a variable goes out of scope the operating system sees the address space where the variable was (is?) at can be used by another program now, or is it?

The book says that global variables are stored in memory and local variables are stored in the run time stack. First of all the run time stack is in memory so I don't see the distinction. How does the operating system know how much space to allocate for the run time stack since the number of items to be pushed on can't be determined before runtime?

Answer (score 0):

When the book says "global variables are stored in memory", what it is referring to is the heap, which is different from the stack. Both are memory but different types of memory.

See here for more details: http://www-ee.eng.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap14/subsection2.1.1.8.html

Answer (score 0):

Disregard for the moment, virtual memory and memory management solutions required by modern operating systems.

Embedded in the executable file is the amount of memory needed for fixed/static data of which your global variables are included.  The data segment (DS) (hardware) register keeps track of these fixed data elements.  The DS amount does not change.  The DS points to a contiguous chunk of memory. If there is not enough contiguous memory, you get an insufficient memory error and the program does not load. As you said, this memory does not "go out of scope" during program execution.

The local variables are allocated from another part of memory managed by the stack segment (SS) register. The amount of memory managed by the SS grows and shrinks during the program's execution. Max and minimum sizes are determined by the operating system (OS). (These sizes are not based on physical memory size in today's complex OSs)

If you exceed the max amount during execution you get a stack-overflow error.

The program does not execute if the min size is not available. So the pgm starts with at least the min amount.  If more SS memory is needed during execution, the OS will grow the memory block - if possible else stack-overflow error.

When a function is invoked, its local variables are allocated from the SS (sort of like how the global variables were allocated in the DS). There are other housekeeping items in the SS such as the where to go when the function exits (i.e. the address of the code after that invoked the function). As functions invoke other functions in a nested fashion, the stack grows and grows. As each function completes execution, control goes back to the invoking function, the completed function's local variables are released and the stack shrinks.

The "heap" memory is another block of memory that grows as needed to hold items that are "created" or "allocated memory space" during program execution (using "malloc" or "new" or some verb like that depending on the language). Like the SS, the OS determines min and max sizes and each pgm starts with at least the min amount.

There are layers of protection built into today's modern cpus, OSs, languages to ensure that the contents of physical memory is treated properly i.e. can not execute data blocks nor write/read code blocks.

Virtual memory, the need to move memory blocks to allow multiple programs to run (memory management) and getting rid of out-of-scope heap items add another layer but the rudiments detailed above still hold true.

Comment: So in short local variables go on the stack and global variables go on the heap, or not necessarily?